# Is it possible to configure TMG to impersonate a domain user for anonymous requests to a website?

Tags: disaster-recovery, isa-server, microsoft-ftmg

I would like to configure Forefront Threat Management Gateway (formerly ISA server) to impersonate a specific domain user for any anonymous request to a particular listener.  For example, for any anonymous request to http://www.mycompany.com, I would like to serve up http://myinternal as though MYDOMAIN/GuestAccount were accessing the site.  Is this even possible in ISA/TMG?  If so, where do I go to configure this?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible in ISA 2006, not sure about TMG